# Combine multiple worksheets using VBA, Receiving Error - Object variable not set (Error 91)

Tags: vba, excel, csv

**Hi**

Im Trying to combine the information that is located on the first sheet from multiple workbooks in to only one master file.. Im getting a error that i cant manage to correct and i was wondering if anybody could give me some feedback regarding how to make it work, I have been using this code before to combine multiple workbooks but i don't really know why i suddenly got this error, This is the code i'm using for the moment and i also copied the error i'm receiving down below , feel free to edit it how ever you want. Im thankful for all feedback

-

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineDataFiles()

Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim MaxNumberFiles As Long, FileIdx As Long, _
    LastDataRow As Long, LastDataCol As Long, _
    HeaderRow As Long, LastOutRow As Long
Dim DataRng As Range, OutRng As Range

'initialize constants
MaxNumberFiles = 2001
HeaderRow = 1 'assume headers are always in row 1
LastOutRow = 1

'prompt user to select files
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With TargetFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

'error trap - don't allow user to pick more than 2000 files
If TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count > MaxNumberFiles Then
    MsgBox ("Too many files selected, please pick more than " & MaxNumberFiles & ". Exiting sub...")
    Exit Sub
End If

'set up the output workbook
Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)

'loop through all files
     For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count

    'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
    Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    Set DataSheet = DataBook.ActiveSheet

    'identify row/column boundaries
    LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastDataCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'if this is the first go-round, include the header
    If FileIdx = 1 Then
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    'if this is NOT the first go-round, then skip the header
    Else
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1 + LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    End If

    'copy the data to the outbook
    DataRng.Copy OutRng

    'close the data book without saving
    DataBook.Close False

    'update the last outbook row
    LastOutRow = OutSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Next FileIdx

'let the user know we're done!
MsgBox ("Combined " & TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count & " files!")

End Sub
```

**Im getting the following Error**

> Object variable not set (Error 91)
>
> There are two steps to creating an object variable. First you must
>   declare the object variable. Then you must assign a valid reference to
>   the object variable using the Set statement. Similarly, a With...End
>   With block must be initialized by executing the With statement entry
>   point. This error has the following causes and solutions:
>
> You attempted to use an object variable that isn't yet referencing a
>   valid object.  Specify or respecify a reference for the object
>   variable. For example, if the Set statement is omitted in the
>   following code, an error would be generated on the reference to
>
> ```
> MyObject 
>
> :
>
> Dim MyObject As Object    ' Create object variable.
> Set MyObject = Sheets(1)    ' Create valid object reference.
> MyCount = MyObject.Count    ' Assign Count value to MyCount.
> ```
>
> - You attempted to use an object variable that has been set to **Nothing.**
>
>   Set MyObject = Nothing    ' Release the object.
>     MyCount = MyObject.Count    ' Make a reference to a released object.
>
> Respecify a reference for the object variable. For example, use a new
>   Set statement to set a new reference to the object.
>
> The object is a valid object, but it wasn't set because the object
>   library in which it is described hasn't been selected in the
>   References dialog box.  Select the object library in the Add
>   References dialog box.
>
> The target of a GoTo statement is inside a With block.  Don't jump
>   into a With block. Make sure the block is initialized by executing the
>   With statement entry point.
>
> You specified a line inside a With block when you chose the Set Next
>   Statement command.  The With block must be initialized by executing
>   the With statement.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Im not sure if it is this you meant but i think it is the following line accourinding the error i'm receiving 


 MyObject 

:

Dim MyObject As Object    ' Create object variable.
Set MyObject = Sheets(1)    ' Create valid object reference.
MyCount = MyObject.Count    ' Assign Count value to MyCount.
You attempted to use an object variable that has been set to Nothing.

Set MyObject = Nothing ' Release the object. MyCount = MyObject.Count ' Make a reference to a released object.

Comment: Don't quote the help text. That is useless. Which line of YOUR code produces the error???? Please edit the question and mark it. You don't need to guess where the error occurs. Just click the Debug button in the error box and the code line will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr:** it would be great if you would reveal the line that is throwing the error in this script as well as more info about the file being operated on at that time, but if I had to guess at a cause I would suggest looking for an empty file.

**Deeper-dive:** there are 7 objects in the mix on this script: `DataBook`, `OutBook`, `DataSheet`, `OutSheet`, `TargetFiles`, `DataRng` and `OutRng`. When I set the `Workbook`, `Worksheet` and `FileDialog` variables, they're pretty straightforward... very little room for things to go wrong.

The `Range` variables, on the other hand... those little guys depend on successful identification of the last row and last column, which leads me to suspect they are the issue:

```
'identify row/column boundaries
    LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastDataCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'if this is the first go-round, include the header
    If FileIdx = 1 Then
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    'if this is NOT the first go-round, then skip the header
    Else
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1 + LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    End If
```

**But what if the first file has an empty** `DataSheet`? In that situation, the `.Find` method will return `Nothing`, and trying to get the `.Row` of `Nothing` will throw a 91 error.

Comment: Is it not possible to just make the vba to ignore the fact that it did not find anything in the datasheet and just to make it keep on working instead of ending the processes half way and just canceling it all

Comment: You can add a condition to protect against the empty sheet case by wrapping the `LastDataRow` and `LastDataCol` calcs in an `If...Then` statement. Here's an MSDN link for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Also -- did you verify that it was a blank sheet causing the error?

Comment: Yes i have done that and the problem is that i cant find all the ones with the blank sheets and take them out so i need to do it some other way

Comment: okej im going to look into the link you sended me i hope u are avaible with some feedback after the resurs if i cant make it work? Thank you dan i'm very thankfull for all support you have been provided to me

Comment: Hey -- I can empathize, programming is frustrating... **but an all-caps shout is not how to go about getting help** and frankly is rude. The SO community is entirely volunteer-based and is offering you near-instantaneous support at no charge. What don't you get? Is it the syntax of an `If...Then` statement causing you heartburn? The strategy behind using an `If...Then` statement in this situation maybe? Help us help you.